# How do I find time complexity using summation?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, graph, graph-algorithm, breadth-first-search

Given Sum of (C + a_k) from k=1 to n, where C is the cost of running to return a list of edges and a_k the number of edges from from node k. How do I solve this summation to find its Theta Notation?

Comment: Sounds liked you're running this on a directed graph. The sum of edges from every node in a directed graph is exactly all of the edges in that graph. Summing constant `c` `n` times is `nc`.

Comment: @Welbog So, it is Theta(n*C)?

Comment: Generally constants are dropped from big-Oh and related notations.

Comment: @Welbog Yes, you are right. This will just leave Theta(n) as a result.

Comment: I believe that is correct, based on your description of the problem.

Comment: @Welbog Sorry, I'm still trying to grasp this. When I worked it out, I had it as Sum( C + a_k) = C * n + Sum(a_k),  and Sum(a_k) from 1 to n is  a_k * n. Which means  Sum(C + a_k) = C * n + a_k * n.  I know constants should be ignored, I'm not sure how to get Theta(n) from this.

Comment: The sum of the a_ks is n, the number of edges. I guess if you want to get very detailed, if there are V vertices and E edges, then there are V a_ks, each with cost C, so just getting the edges is C * V = O(V). As each edge is operated on once, presumably, then there are an additional E operations, so the result is O(V+E). However the problem as stated doesn't say what's done with the edges; if they're just returned but never iterated on, then you're only doing V operations total.

Comment: @welbog Thank you for the help. I understand it now!